# JavaFX: how to hide the item selection after having selected an item

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

I made a WebEngine where i can use favorite Web URLS from a Choicebox (= favBox).
After having chosen an item, the item is shown and  the website is loading. But my problem is: the item can still be seen for the rest of the session. How can I hide the item selection and just show the ChoiceBox without items?

Thanks a lot

```
@FXML
private void handleFavoritLoading(MouseEvent event) {
    //favBox is a ChoiceBox
    favBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            System.out.println("OK");
            browser.load(favBox.getItems().get(newValue.intValue()));
            // how to make the favBox not showing the selected item???



        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the selection of a ChoiceBox, then nothing will be selected in it.

```
favBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                browser.load(newValue);
                favBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        }
);
```

Note that this behavior is a little bit strange as most of the time you probably want the selected choice to continue to be shown after selection.  However, if you don't want the standard operation and want to immediately clear the choice after selection, you can always use the sample code provided here.

Sample app:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList;

public class HiddenChoices extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine browser = webView.getEngine();
        VBox.setVgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        ChoiceBox<String> favBox = new ChoiceBox<>(
                observableArrayList(
                        "http://www.google.com",
                        "http://andrew-hoyer.com/experiments/cloth/",
                        "http://www.effectgames.com/demos/canvascycle/",
                        "http://www.zynaps.com/site/experiments/environment.html?mesh=bart.wft"
                )
        );

        favBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (newValue != null) {
                        browser.load(newValue);
                        favBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    }
                }
        );

        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
        progress.progressProperty().bind(browser.getLoadWorker().progressProperty());
        progress.visibleProperty().bind(browser.getLoadWorker().runningProperty());

        HBox controls = new HBox(10, favBox, progress);
        controls.setMinHeight(HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        new VBox(10, controls, webView)
                )
        );
        stage.show();

        favBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```